# Filtering results in python, I need one variable but only if based on another

Tags: python, json, filter

After pretty printing `s.get_snaps()`

I get results that look like this:

```
[{u'id': u'405976417440944459r',
  u'media_id': None,
  u'media_type': 3,
  u'opened': 1417440944459L,
  u'recipient': None,
  u'screenshot_count': None,
  u'sender': u'test.account3',
  u'sent': 1417440944459L,
  u'status': 1,
  u'time': 0},
 {u'id': u'281814417440226067r',
  u'media_id': None,
  u'media_type': 3,
  u'opened': 1417440226067L,
  u'recipient': None,
  u'screenshot_count': None,
  u'sender': u'test.account2',
  u'sent': 1417440226067L,
  u'status': 1,
  u'time': 0},
 {u'id': u'735386417439697190r',
  u'media_id': None,
  u'media_type': 1,
  u'opened': 1417439697190L,
  u'recipient': None,
  u'screenshot_count': None,
  u'sender': u'test.account4',
  u'sent': 1417439697190L,
  u'status': 1,
  u'time': 7},
```

What I need is all `u'sender'` in a list.
Which I can do easily by:

```
snaps = s.get_snaps()

newfile = open("newfile.txt", "w")

for sender in snaps:
    newfile.write(sender[u'sender'] + "\n")
```

This is what I know and have researched so far, but I'm going to need to make it a little bit more tricky.
What I need next is the following.

Again I need a list with the senders, but only if `u'media_type': 3,`

So I need to filter my results, narrow them down to I only have senders left that match `media_type: 3`
Then I need to remember those names, store them somewhere.

Because I will need to use them in the following code: `s.add_friend(sender)`
Thus adding them to my friends list, one by one.

My question is; how can I filter the results of `s.get_snaps()`
So that it will only result in showing the names of `u'sender` that match `u'media_type': 3,`
Then remember them, and add the sender names one by one using `s.add_friend(sender)`

I was thinking of storing them in a text file, then adding them by `for line in file`
But I was hoping there was a more "elegant" solution that doesn't require additional files to be created, a way for python to perhaps remember it in the script itself?

To anyone that is able to help me, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter using an `if` statement:

```
for sender in snaps:
    if sender['media_type'] == 3:
        s.add_friend(sender)
```

or building a list of only matching entries:

```
matching = [sender for sender in snaps if sender['media_type'] == 3]
```

The latter creates a *new* list with only matching senders.

If you only wanted the sender accounts, then extract those from the dictionaries while filtering:

```
matching_accounts = [sender['sender'] for sender in snaps if sender['media_type'] == 3]
```

Comment: It's not working, maybe because of the \n? or 'u not being stripped from the senders name?

Comment: @Snowlav: there are no newlines in the sample data you provided, and `u` is not part of the value, it is only a type specifier (they are Unicode strings). If all you have is ASCII characters in the strings, you can use byte strings (no `u`) and Unicode strings (with `u` prefix) interchangeably and Python will encode / decode as needed.

Comment: @Snowlav: you'll need to define what 'not working' means here. Do you get an error? An empty list? `s.add_friend()` is never called? etc.

Comment: I get no response in command prompt, just a blank line.
And when I check the test.account1, no friends are added, while test accounts 2 and 3 do have a request pending.

Comment: @Snowlav: have you tried adding some `print` statements to see what your code is doing?

Comment: I just pretty printed: `matching = [sender for sender in snaps if sender['media_type'] == 3]` and it showed my 2 test accounts which is great! though I get the whole wall of info, not just the "test.account2+3" that I'm looking for.

Comment: @Snowlav: then extract that information with `sender['sender']`; I showed you how to filter the dictionaries only here.

Comment: awesome, so far it pretty prints: [u'test.account3', u'test.account2'] I tried changing ['sender] to [u'sender'] but that did not get rid of the `u'`

Comment: @Snowlav: again, the `u` is only a *type indicator*. You don't need to get rid of it, you just have Unicode strings.

Comment: so when writing it to a file, the `u'` will be gone? Because `s.add_friends()` wont work with the `u'`

Comment: @Snowlav: I was assuming you'd not write this to a file but call `s.add_friends()` directly. What arguments does that function take? If you were to write to a file, generally speaking the data will be encoded (and the `u` prefix will not be part of the value written).

Comment: s.add_friend(matching_account) works, but only partly. Only the last account (test.account3) in this case gets added back. BTW I really appreciate the help you have been giving me thus far, I sincerely do.

Comment: @Snowlav: maybe make that a *new* question then, but include details of how `s.add_friend()` is supposed to work.

Comment: Hmm I've been over this again, and it seems that `s.add_friend()` only accepts one friend at the time, writing these results to a list and then using the list would be best I think. Is there a special way to write `matching_account = ([sender['sender'] for sender in snaps if sender['media_type'] == 3])` to a file? since f.write() does not seem to work

Comment: @Snowlav: why not immediately call the method? First example in my code.

Comment: the first example needs to extract only the "sender name" (test.account2) (test.account3). and it does not do that, your last example does. and when using the s.add_friend(matching_accounts) it only adds the last account on the list, because s.add_friend() only takes 1 friend, not multiple. I think it needs to be ran in a loop, when using a textfile, I can do it a line at the time.

Comment: damn I'm so stupid, I played with the code a little bit and: `for sender in snaps:
    if sender['media_type'] == 3:
        s.add_friend(sender[u'sender'])` seems to work perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension for this

```
>>> [d[u'sender'] for d in s.get_snaps() if d['media_type'] == 3]
['test.account3', 'test.account2']
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution :)